# trouble updating mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I have these codes, used to update mysql database

AIS.php-used to input pnum and then new.php will show the corresponding record for the pnum

```
<style>
input { font-size: 16px;}
</style>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div id="main_content">


</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>






<table width="900" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>


<form name="form1" method="post" action="new.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="16" style="background:#9ACD32; color:white; border:white 1px solid; text-align: center"><strong><font size="3">UPDATE IN-PATIENT</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td width="54"><font size="3">Patient #</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="pnum" type="text" id="pnum" maxlength="4"></td>
</tr>

<td width="54"><font size="3">Hospital #</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="hnum" type="text" id="hospnum" maxlength="4"></td>

<td width="41"><font size="3">Room #</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="rnum" type="text" id="rnum" maxlength="4"></td>

<td width="67"><font size="3">Date</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="adate" type="text" id="adate" maxlength="15">

<td width="67"><font size="3">Time</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="adtime" type="text" id="adtime" maxlength="15">

</td>




</tr>


<tr>
<td><font size="3">Last Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="lname" type="text" id="lname" maxlength="15"></td>
<td><font size="3">First Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" maxlength="15"></td>
<td><font size="3">Middle Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mname" type="text" id="mname" maxlength="15"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><font size="3">Civil Status</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="cs" type="text" id="cs" maxlength="7"></td>
<td><font size="3">Age</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="age" type="text" id="age" maxlength="3"></td>
<td><font size="3">Birthday</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="bday" type="text" id="bday" maxlength="11"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Address</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="ad" type="text" id="ad" maxlength="25"></td>
<td><font size="3">Telephone #</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="telnum" type="text" id="telnum" maxlength="11"></td>

<td width="23"><font size="3">Sex</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="174"><input name="sex" type="text" id="sex" maxlength="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Pls. Check</td>
<td>:</td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats1" value="0">
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="SSS" value="SSS">SSS</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td>:</td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats2" value="0">
<td><input name="stats2" type="checkbox" id="nonmed" value="NonMedicare">Non Medicare</td>

<td><font size="3"></td>
<td>:</td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats3" value="0">
<td><input name="stats3" type="checkbox" id="sh" value="stockholder">Stockholder</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats4" value="0">
<td><input name="stats4" type="checkbox" id="gsis" value="GSIS">GSIS</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats5" value="0">
<td><input name="stats5" type="checkbox" id="senior" value="seniorcitizen">Senior-Citizen</td>


<tr>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats6" value="0">
<td><input name="stats6" type="checkbox" id="dep" value="dependent">Dependent</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats7" value="0">
<td><input name="stats7" type="checkbox" id="emp" value="employee">Employee</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats8" value="0">
<td><input name="stats8" type="text" id="" value="" maxlength="15">Others</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Admitting/Attending Nurse</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="nurse" type="text" id="nurse" maxlength="15"></td>

</tr>






<tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search"></td>

</form>



</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td>

</tr>
</table>

</html>
```

new.php

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
input { font-size: 16px;}
</style>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div id="main_content">

</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE PNUM='{$_POST["pnum"]}'");
?>

<table width="900" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="16" style="background:#9ACD32; color:white; border:white 1px solid; text-align: center"><strong><font size="3">UPDATE IN-PATIENT INFORMATION SHEET</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">
<input type='hidden' name="pnum" value="">
<td width="54"><font size="3">Hospital #</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="hnum" type="text"  maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $row["HOSPNUM"]; ?> ">
</td>

<td width="41"><font size="3">Room #</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="rnum" type="text"  maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $row["ROOMNUM"]; ?>">
</td>

<td width="67"><font size="3">Admission Date</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="adate" type="text"  maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $row["ADATE"]; ?>">
</td>

<td width="67"><font size="3">Admission Time</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="adtime" type="text" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $row["ADTIME"]; ?>">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Last Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="lname" type="text" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $row["LASTNAME"]; ?>"></td>
<td><font size="3">First Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="fname" type="text" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $row["FIRSTNAME"]; ?>"></td>
<td><font size="3">Middle Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mname" type="text" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $row["MIDNAME"]; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Civil Status</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="cs" type="text" maxlength="7" value="<?php echo $row["CSTAT"]; ?>"></td>
<td><font size="3">Age</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="age" type="text" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $row["AGE"]; ?>"></td>
<td><font size="3">Birthday</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="bday" type="text"  maxlength="7"value="<?php echo $row["BDAY"]; ?>"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Address</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="ad" type="text"  maxlength="25" value="<?php echo $row["ADDRESS"]; ?>"></td>
<td><font size="3">Telephone #</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="telnum" type="text" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $row["TELNUM"]; ?>"></td>

<td width="23"><font size="3">Sex</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="174"><input name="sex" type="text" maxlength="1" value="<?php echo $row["SEX"]; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Pls. Check</td>
<td>:</td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats1" value="0">
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="SSS"  maxlength="3" value="SSS">SSS</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td>:</td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats2" value="0">
<td><input name="stats2" type="checkbox" id="nonmed" maxlength="9" value="Non Med">Non Medicare</td>

<td><font size="3"></td>
<td>:</td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats3" value="0">
<td><input name="stats3" type="checkbox" id="sh" value="stockholder">Stockholder</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats4" value="0">
<td><input name="stats4" type="checkbox" id="gsis" value="gsis">GSIS</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats5" value="0">
<td><input name="stats5" type="checkbox" id="senior"  value="senior citizen">Senior-Citizen</td>


<tr>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats6" value="0">
<td><input name="stats6" type="checkbox" id="dep"  value="Dependent">Dependent</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats7" value="0">
<td><input name="stats7" type="checkbox" id="emp" value="Employee">Employee</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats8" value="0">
<td><input name="stats8" type="text" id="" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $row["STAT8"]; ?>" >Others</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Admitting/Attending Nurse</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="nurse" type="text" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $row["NURSE"]; ?>"></td>

</tr>

  <tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update"></td>

</form>



</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>




<?php } ?>
```

Then finally the update.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE t2 SET HOSPNUM ='$_POST[hnum]', ROOMNUM='$_POST[rnum]', ADATE='$_POST[adate]',  ADTIME='$_POST[adtime]', LASTNAME='$_POST[lname]', FIRSTNAME='$_POST[fname]', MIDNAME='$_POST[mname]', CSTAT='$_POST[cs]', AGE='$_POST[age]', BDAY='$_POST[bday]', ADDRESS='$_POST[ad]', SEX='$_POST[sex]', 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       STAT='$_POST[stats1]', STAT2='$_POST[stats2]', STAT3='$_POST[stats3]', STAT4='$_POST[stats4]', STAT5='$_POST[stats5]', STAT6='$_POST[stats6]', STAT7='$_POST[stats7]', STAT8='$_POST[stats8]', NURSE='$_POST[nurse]'              
WHERE PNUM ='$_POST[pnum]'");


echo "<script>alert('Data Successfully Updated')</script>";
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

The problem is, I didn't show the text box corresponding to the pnum(primary key) to prevent it from being updated. Do you know of any technique that would not allow the pnum to be updated even if the text box corresponding to it is shown?

Comment: sorry, can it be access by people?

Comment: oh my this cries for sql injection

Comment: don't put all the code here, just the specific code causing the problem, it also makes it easier for others to answer your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to update it, but still need it in your query you can do:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col` = `col` WHERE `id` = …
```

Comment: I figured it out, I'll just set the input to hidden, but thanks anyway:
<td width="168"><input  type="hidden" name="pnum" type="text" id="pnum" maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $row["PNUM"]; ?>"></td>